# citation question (different authors, same year, same surname) [natbib]

Tags: citing, natbib

I was trying to cite two papers written in the same year but by different authors. The bibliography package I used was \usepackage{natbib}.

```
...
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

\cite{pchan02} argues that.... However, \cite{mchan02} points out a problem...

\bibliography{listwork}
 \bibliographystyle{custom1}
\end{document}
```

However, the output I got was:

'Chan (2002a) argues that.... However, Chan (2002b) points out a problem...'

The same with the bibliography list at the end: 'Chan, Peter. 2002a. ...' 'Chan, Mary. 2002b. ...'

It seems that natbib judges whether two authors are the same just by the family name. In this case, the two Chan's are actually different authors ('Peter Chan' vs. 'Mary Chan'). So, the desired output for me would be:

'Chan (2002) argues that.... However, Chan (2002) points out a problem...'

Is there a way I can change things so two authors would be taken to be the same only when the **both** the first and surnames are identical? That is, if I'm citing two works by Susan Chan in the same year, I'd like the outputs of \cite{schan07a} and \cite{schan07b} to be exactly 'Chan (2007a)' and 'Chan (2007b)' (and I have no problem with this; my compiler gave me exactly these outputs.) The problem I have is that two different authors with the same surname are also treated the same person, incorrectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! (I searched for similar questions on StackExchange, but the solutions are inapplicable in my case. I'm using natbib.)

Here's a list of entries from the **listwork.bib** file:

```
@article{pchan02,
  title={The meaning of life},
  author={Chan, Peter},
  journal={Journal of Happiness},
  pages={1--3},
  year={2002},
}   

@article{mchan02,
  title={On the meaning of the meaning of life},
  author={Chan, Mary},
  journal={Journal of Happiness},
  pages={4--6},
  year={2002},
}   

@article{schan07a,
  title={On meaning},
  author={Chan, Susan},
  journal={Journal of Happiness},
  pages={10--13},
  year={2007},
}   

@article{schan07b,
  title={On the meaning of meaning},
  author={Chan, Susan},
  journal={Journal of Happiness},
  pages={14--16},
  year={2007},
}
```

Here's the code from the **custom1.bst** file:

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    url
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label short.list }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}

STRINGS { s t }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {date.block}
{
  new.block
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "\/}" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {capitalize}
{ "u" change.case$ "t" change.case$ }

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }

 % Here are the language-specific definitions for explicit words.
 % Each function has a name bbl.xxx where xxx is the English word.
 % The language selected here is ENGLISH
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "ed." }    %% < eds. (Alexis)

FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
{ "ed." }

FUNCTION {bbl.edby}
{ "edited by" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "edition" }

FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "volume" }

FUNCTION {bbl.of}
{ "of" }

FUNCTION {bbl.number}
{ "number" }

FUNCTION {bbl.nr}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "" }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "" }

FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}
{ "chapter" }

FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}
{ "Technical Report" }

FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}
{ "Master's thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}
{ "Doctoral Dissertation" }

MACRO {jan} {"January"}

MACRO {feb} {"February"}

MACRO {mar} {"March"}

MACRO {apr} {"April"}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"June"}

MACRO {jul} {"July"}

MACRO {aug} {"August"}

MACRO {sep} {"September"}

MACRO {oct} {"October"}

MACRO {nov} {"November"}

MACRO {dec} {"December"}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}


INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { nameptr #1 >
        { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$  }
        { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}" format.name$  }
      if$
    't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
          "," *
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                { bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {

                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                { bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.key}
{ empty$
    { key field.or.null }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names
      editor num.names$ #1 >
        { ", " * bbl.editors * }
        { ", " * bbl.editor * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names.ed
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.note}
{
  url empty$
    'skip$
    { "\urlprefix\url{" url * "}" * output }
  if$
 note empty$
    { "" }
    { note #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "{" =
        'skip$
        { output.state mid.sentence =
          { "l" }
          { "u" }
        if$
        change.case$
        }
      if$
      note #2 global.max$ substring$ *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.full.names}
{'s :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                { bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.full.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.full}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {make.full.names}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.full
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.full
        'author.key.full
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[{" write$
  label write$
  ")" make.full.names duplicate$ short.list =
     { pop$ }
     { * }
   if$
  "}]{" * write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{
  't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in capitalize
  " " * }

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * "; set to ????" * warning$
       pop$ "????" }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label *
  before.all 'output.state :=
  after.sentence 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title "t" change.case$ emphasize  %% < title emphasize (Alexis)
}

FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$ * *
}

FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
        'skip$
        { bbl.of space.word * series emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { series empty$
            { number }
        { output.state mid.sentence =
            { bbl.number }
            { bbl.number capitalize }
          if$
          number tie.or.space.connect
          bbl.in space.word * series *
        }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}


FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
    { "" }
    { output.state mid.sentence =
        { edition "l" change.case$ " " * bbl.edition * }
        { edition "t" change.case$ " " * bbl.edition * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { multiresult }

FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}

FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { pages n.dashify }
        { pages }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ":" *
          pages n.dashify *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  format.journal.pages
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
        { bbl.chapter }
        { type "l" change.case$ }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.connect
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

% The original format.in.ed.booktitle (capitalize proceedings titles)--Alexis
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.proctitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { editor empty$
        { word.in booktitle emphasize * }
        { word.in booktitle emphasize *
          ", " *
          editor num.names$ #1 >
            { bbl.editors }
            { bbl.editor }
          if$
          * " " *
          format.in.editors *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { editor empty$
        %% Added: "t" change.case$  (Alexis)
        { word.in booktitle "t" change.case$ emphasize * }
        { word.in booktitle "t" change.case$ emphasize *
          ", " *
          editor num.names$ #1 >
            { bbl.editors }
            { bbl.editor }
          if$
          * " " *
          format.in.editors *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$
      type "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ type empty$
    { bbl.techrep }
    'type
  if$
  number empty$
    { "t" change.case$ }
    { number tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
  word.in
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      word.in
    }
    { bbl.volume capitalize
      volume tie.or.space.connect
      bbl.of space.word *
    }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
  word.in
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  address empty$ t empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      address empty$
        'skip$
        { address * }
      if$
      t empty$
        'skip$
        { address empty$
            'skip$
            { ": " * }
          if$
          t *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher empty$
    { "empty publisher in " cite$ * warning$
      ""
    }
    { publisher }
  if$
  format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {format.organization.address}
{ organization empty$
    { "" }
    { organization }
  if$
  format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal
      emphasize
      "journal" output.check
      add.blank
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  howpublished output
  address output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    {
      format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
      format.edition output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    %% Was: format.in.ed.booktitle (need different capitalization-- Alexis)
    { format.in.ed.proctitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.pages output
      new.sentence
      publisher empty$
        { format.organization.address output }
        { organization output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }

FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  organization address new.block.checkb
  organization output
  address output
  format.edition output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  bbl.mthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title output
  new.block
  howpublished output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  bbl.phdthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.editors output
  editor format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  new.sentence
  publisher empty$
    { format.organization.address output }
    { organization output
      format.publisher.address output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" output.check
  address output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.note "note" output.check
%% --> begin: changes by Alexis
  address empty$
    'skip$
    { address output.nonnull }
  if$
  month empty$
    'skip$
    { month " " * year * output.nonnull }
  if$
%% <-- end: changes by Alexis  
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }

READ

FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}

INTEGERS { len }

FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      " " * bbl.etal *
    }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            {
              " " * bbl.etal *
            }
            { bbl.and space.word * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
              * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.lab.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.label}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {calc.short.authors}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.label
        'author.key.label
      if$
    }
  if$
  'short.list :=
}

FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ calc.short.authors
  short.list
  "("
  *
  year duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "????" }
     'skip$
  if$
  *
  'label :=
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  ""
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{ll{ }}{  ff{ }}{  jj{ }}"
      format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          "   "  *
          namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
            { "zzzzz" * }
            { t sortify * }
          if$
        }
        { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}

FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { editor sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.sort}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need editor or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  label sortify
  "    "
  *
  type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.sort
        'author.sort
      if$
    }
  if$
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.label :=
  sort.label
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {presort}

SORT

STRINGS { last.label next.extra }

INTEGERS { last.extra.num number.label }

FUNCTION {initialize.extra.label.stuff}
{ #0 int.to.chr$ 'last.label :=
  "" 'next.extra :=
  #0 'last.extra.num :=
  #0 'number.label :=
}

FUNCTION {forward.pass}
{ last.label label =
    { last.extra.num #1 + 'last.extra.num :=
      last.extra.num int.to.chr$ 'extra.label :=
    }
    { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
      "" 'extra.label :=
      label 'last.label :=
    }
  if$
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
}

FUNCTION {reverse.pass}
{ next.extra "b" =
    { "a" 'extra.label := }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label 'next.extra :=
  extra.label
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    { "{\natexlab{" swap$ * "}}" * }
  if$
  'extra.label :=
  label extra.label * 'label :=
}

EXECUTE {initialize.extra.label.stuff}

ITERATE {forward.pass}

REVERSE {reverse.pass}

FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}
{ sort.label
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {bib.sort.order}

SORT

FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{" number.label int.to.str$ * "}" *
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax"
  write$ newline$
  "  \def\url#1{{\tt #1}}\fi"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi"
  write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

Comment: Are you free to use bilatex/biber instead of natbib/BibTeX? The reason I ask is that it's fairly  straightforward to implement your formatting objective in biblatex.

Comment: Thanks Mico! What changes do I need to make in order to use bilatex/biber? Do I need to change the bib or bst file? (PS: I'm using Overleaf - the online editor)

Comment: See [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/5001) for a general introduction to biblatex. See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/5001) for the main differences between natbib/bibtex on the one hand and biblatex/biber on the other.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but your citation key really should be unique. "Chan (2002) vs. Chan (2002)" would confuse me no end.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. No change was done to your .bib file to use `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa,
backend=biber,
natbib=true,
]
{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname37.bib}
@article{pchan02,
    title={The meaning of life},
    author={Chan, Peter},
    journal={Journal of Happiness},
    pages={1--3},
    year={2002},
}   

@article{mchan02,
    title={On the meaning of the meaning of life},
    author={Chan, Mary},
    journal={Journal of Happiness},
    pages={4--6},
    year={2002},
}   

@article{schan07a,
    title={On meaning},
    author={Chan, Susan},
    journal={Journal of Happiness},
    pages={10--13},
    year={2007},
}   

@article{schan07b,
    title={On the meaning of meaning},
    author={Chan, Susan},
    journal={Journal of Happiness},
    pages={14--16},
    year={2007},
}   

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname37.bib}

\begin{document}

CITE
  
\cite{pchan02} argues that.... However, \cite{mchan02} points out a problem...

CITEP

\citep{pchan02} argues that.... However, \citep{mchan02} points out a problem...
  
  
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

If you're free to use `biblatex` and biber instead of `natbib` and BibTeX, the formatting you seek for names in citation call-outs is enabled by default.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% create a bib file 'on the fly'
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{pchan02,
  title={The meaning of life}, author={Chan, Peter}, year=2002}   
@misc{mchan02,
  title={On the meaning of the meaning of life}, author={Chan, Mary}, year=2002}   
@misc{tchan03a,
  title="Thoughts", author="Ted Chan", year=2004}
@misc{tchan03b,
  title="Further thoughts", author="Tim Chan", year=2004}
@misc{schan07a,
  title={On meaning}, author={Chan, Susan}, year=2007}   
@misc{schan07b,
  title={On the meaning of meaning}, author={Chan, Susan}, year=2007}   
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} 
    % option 'natbib' enables use of \citet and \citep
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\citep{pchan02,mchan02}, \citep{tchan03a,tchan03b} \citep{schan07a,schan07b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```